# How to make a autologin in c#

Tags: c#, session-cookies, autologin

I have written a website in aspx with c#. Now I want to create a auto login feature for a specific user with c#. It should recognize the specific user based on his hostname or IP address and then create a cookie.

Is this a good approach? Thank you.

Comment: No. Just get them to login like everyone else. Don't go reinventing authentication. A lot of hard work went into getting the asp.net login flows right. Make use of them. It's surprisingly easy to get this seriously wrong. Do you want to take such a gamble?

Comment: Both hostname and ip address can easily by spoofed - so it's quite bad idea to rely on it.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I totally agree with you. But i forgot to mention that i made the website for intranet purposes. We have a notebook that is connected to a tv. The tv runs all day in background on the floor. At the moment we need to log us in every morning. We want to bypass this step for this specific notebook.

Comment: If your notebook doesn't use DHCP for Ips, then you could use the IP-address check.

Comment: use windows authentication and check the save credentials it will only ask the first time and never ask again for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

**Ip-Check**
To page load ->

```
if(Request.UserHostAddress.Equals(allowedIp))
{  
 Session["loggedIn"] = true;
}
```

This is only for one ip. If you wanna use more ips check this out

```
string[] allowedIps = new string[2] {"127.0.0.1","10.10.1.10"};
for(int n = 0;n < allowedIps.Length;n++) {  
  if(Request.UserHostAddress.Equals(allowedIps[n])) {  
    Session["loggedIn"] = true;
  }
}
```